# Распознавание нескольких образов на одном изображении

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Я написал сверточную нейронную сеть, натренировал модель, и теперь она достаточно точно может определять образ, который есть на фотографии.

Но теперь мне нужно сделать так, чтобы она определяла все образы, которые есть на одной фотографии. То есть, надо как-то разрезать исходную фотографию на части, а затем идентифицировать каждый.

Как это сделать? Пишу на Python3, keras. Код обучения и распознавания:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import random
import pickle
import cv2
import os
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.models import load_model
from imutils import paths


matplotlib.use("Agg")

categories = ['bread', 'chicken', 'cucumbers', 'dry_peas', 'eggs',
              'green_peas', 'kolbasa', 'potato', 'raw_beef',
              'spaghetti', 'tomatoes']

dataset = "ingredients"
model_path = "test_model.model"
label_bin = "test_model.pickle"
plot = "output/test_model_plot.png"

print("[INFO] loading images...")
data = []
labels = []

imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(dataset)))
random.seed(42)
random.shuffle(imagePaths)

for imagePath in imagePaths:
    try:
        image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (32, 32))
        data.append(image / 255)

        label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
        labels.append(categories.index(label))
    except Exception as e:
        print("[WARNING]", e)

data = np.array(data)
print(labels)
labels = to_categorical(np.array(labels))
print(labels)

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
                                                  test_size=0.2,
                                                  random_state=42)

lb = LabelBinarizer()
trainY = lb.fit_transform(trainY)
testY = lb.transform(testY)
'''
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(len(lb.classes_), activation="softmax"))
'''
model = load_model('test_model.model')

INIT_LR = 0.01
EPOCHS = 150

print("[INFO] training network...")
opt = SGD(lr=INIT_LR)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
              metrics=["accuracy"])

H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY),
              epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=32)

print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predictions = model.predict(testX, batch_size=32)
print(predictions)
#print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1)
#    predictions.argmax(axis=1), target_names=lb.classes_))

N = np.arange(0, EPOCHS)
plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
print(H.history.keys())
plt.plot(N, H.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
plt.plot(N, H.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot(N, H.history["accuracy"], label="train_acc")
plt.plot(N, H.history["val_accuracy"], label="val_acc")
plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy (Simple NN)")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig(plot)

print("[INFO] serializing network and label binarizer...")
model.save(model_path)
f = open(label_bin, "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(lb))
f.close()
```

и

```
import argparse
import pickle
import cv2
import flask
import werkzeug
from keras.models import load_model
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as tb
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import set_session
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model

import sys
sys.modules['keras'] = keras

class FoodRecognizer:
    def __init__(self, model, label_bin, size, flatten):
        self.label_bin = label_bin
        self.size = size
        self.width, self.height = self.size
        self.flatten = flatten

        print("[INFO] loading network and label binarizer...")
        set_session(sess)
        self.model = load_model(model)
        self.lb = pickle.loads(open(self.label_bin, "rb").read())

    def load_image(self, image_file):
        image = cv2.imread(image_file)
        output = image.copy()
        image = cv2.resize(image, self.size)
        image = image / 255.0
        image = image.reshape(1, *image.shape)

        self.image = image

    def recognize(self):
        preds = self.model.predict(self.image)
        result = list(preds[0])

        for i in range(len(result)):
            print(categories[i].ljust(10, " "), result[i], sep='\t')

        i = preds.argmax(axis=1)[0]

        print()

        out = sorted(result)[-3:][::-1]
        print("Скорее всего, на фотографии:")
        for o in out:
            print(categories[result.index(o)], f"{round(o * 100, 2)}%")

        label = self.lb.classes_[i]

        return label


app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_request():
    print(flask.request.files.to_dict())
    imagefile = flask.request.files['image']

    filename = werkzeug.utils.secure_filename(imagefile.filename)
    print("\nReceived image File name : " + imagefile.filename)
    imagefile.save('images/' + str(filename))

    MFR.load_image('images/' + filename)
    print(MFR.image)
    print('images/' + filename)

    with graph.as_default():
        set_session(sess)
        result = MFR.recognize()
    print(result)

    return categories[result]


categories = ['bread', 'chicken', 'cucumbers', 'dry_peas', 'eggs',
              'green_peas', 'kolbasa', 'potato', 'raw_beef',
              'spaghetti', 'tomatoes']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    model_path = "test_model.model"
    label_path = "test_model.pickle"

    size = (32, 32)
    flatten = 1

    sess = tf.Session()
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    MFR = FoodRecognizer(model_path, label_path, size, flatten)

    #MFR.load_image("images/test_image.jpg")
    #print(categories[MFR.recognize()])

    set_session(sess)

    app.run(host='10.61.4.238', debug=True, threaded=False)
```